# SOQL Query to find if Open activities exist on case

Tags: soql

Is there a way to return count(open activities) on case when I build a SOQL query in workbench ?

Ex:

```
SELECT Id, {count(open activities)} FROM Case WHERE AND Status = 'open' AND {open activities != null}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Count()** can only be used in root queries, it cannot be used in nested or inner query. Hence, this is how you can achieve -

```
integer openActivitiesCount = 0;
List<Case> csList = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM OpenActivities) FROM Case Where Status =: 'New'];
for (Case cs : csList){
    openActivitiesCount = openActivitiesCount + cs.OpenActivities.size();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be querying the Task or Event object with WhatId as Case like below

```
SELECT count(id) FROM Task WHERE WhatId =: caseId AND IsClosed = False

SELECT count(id) FROM Event WHERE WhatId =: caseId AND IsClosed = False
```

Hope it helps.